# Identify surface mount component: DIP-6 size marked V216HC4 newline 22301

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I have no idea what this component is, but the package looks roughly like an SMT version of an old-fashioned DIP package with 6 pins and pin 5 cut off (shortened, hanging).

The markings are very small and hard to read because of the reflection from the conformal coating, but I think I read them correctly.

- Package: DIP-6 (black 6-pin DIP-like SMT package with pin 5 cut off)
- Markings: V216HC4 newline 22301 (as best I can read through conformal coating)
- PCB-ID: LPC101, LPC102, LPC103

Please have a look and see if you can identify it. I had no luck with many online searches.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly a variation of the Panasonic [AQV216H](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/315/aqv_dip_short_circuit_protection_catalog-1299266.pdf) MOSFET-output SSR.

Panasonic offers the AQV258H5 in a 5-pin SMD DIP for applications that require higher creepage distances than the standard 6-pin SMD DIP.

Comment: I found a picture of the [AQV219HAX](http://images.100y.com.tw/images/product_jpg_original/A072324.jpg) which is in a 5 pin DIP (SMD) package according to the [datasheet](https://mediac.industry.panasonic.eu/p/2022-10/Automotive_DIP6-1a_DIP8-2a.pdf?VersionId=FrsdiLekPUAQ8Sq7cZdKu3bl0XL88q2T). If Panasonics naming is consistent then it would be a [AQV216HAX](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Panasonic-Industrial-Devices/AQV216HAX?qs=2rFUEsTwVNzVeys0idMewQ%3D%3D).